# python embedded command prompt eval in root scope

Tags: python, exec, eval, command-prompt, pyside

I'm creating a python application using the PySide Qt implementation and as part of the ui i want a built in command prompt so i can issue python commands that are not implemented in the interface. My first attempt was to use `eval(contents_of_text_box)` but this does not resolve expressions or execute in the root scope. The next attempt was to use `exec(contents_of_text_box)` which got one step closer and ran the expressions but still not in the correct scope.

This area is a bit great for me so im interested in best practices and how other people have done this. Ideally i need a way to access pre existing program variables without crashing the entire application if the `exec()` command fails

I understand that `exec()` and `eval()` are often considered dangerous so I'd like to be cautious and hear the prevailing wisdom regarding my situation

Comment: What's the "correct scope"? You can specify the scope you want passing dictionaries as globals or locals to `exec`/`eval`.

Comment: this is what I've read but `eval('code', globals(), globals())` doesn't seem to work

Comment: [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) returns the global symbol table for the _current module_.

Comment: Note that `eval('code')` is equivalent to `eval('code', globals(), locals())`, i.e. without specifying the context the current context is used. You generally *don't* want to execute code in the current context since you give *full* access to anything in your program.